# Looking to bold certain sections of a WPF RTF text through C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, rtf

I'm looking for a code-how that can bold selective words and/or lines of text within one of WPF's RichTextBoxes, so that, for example, I could have code that ensures the word `bananabread` would be automatically set to bold whenever it were typed. Another example of this could be setting an entire line to bold if it begins with the word "Therefore."

I'm aware that you can bold specific lines via XAML, and I know that pressing Ctrl + B can bold specific words while in the editor itself, but how can I go about doing this through C#?

Comment: Does using the [`TextChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged?view=netframework-4.8) event work?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with **RTF**; Microsoft's somewhat archaic, mildly documented,  unsupported, Rich Text Format (which dates from early 1990s Word implementations)

Comment: Flydog: Yes, it is a RTF textbox.

Comment: Do you mean a RichTextBox? If so, you're working with a FlowDocument internally, not a RTF file.

Comment: I was under the impression that a RichTextBox is simply a textbox with RTF support, no? Either way, it is a RichTextBox object.